# LuaTex precompiled header fails with Unknown color stack number 1

Tags: initex

I'm running on the Linux system LuaTex, 1.0.4. Since the compilation time takes quite some time - especially to create the ToC I thought I can precompile the header. With the precomiled header I try to run (as file `Main_2.tex`)

```
\begin{document}
    Hello World
\end{document}
```

`luatex -shell-escape "&preamble Main_2.tex"` which fails always with

```
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty)) (./Main_2.out)
(./Main_2.out) (/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/oberdiek/pdflscape.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/lscape.sty))
! Unknown color stack number 1.
<to be read again>
```

The preamble is

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85} % for the watermark to be transparent (with the package)
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage[a4paper,includeheadfoot,margin=2.54cm]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{enumerate} % for enumeration to change
\usepackage{xcolor} % for highlighting AND background images-color!!!
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref} % for links and PDF-specifica (and Umlaute in PDF meta-data)
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec} % to have the section NOT justify, i.e. the lines can be shorter (for linebreak)
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-\do\_} % for breaking long URLS additonally
\usepackage[all]{nowidow} % prevents orphans and widows
\usepackage{hyphenat} % allows hyphenation of compound words like 'Test- und Produktivszenarien' (see source code)
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX} % to have the automatics ligatures of TeX
\setmainfont{Liberation Sans}  % use different font  (#xxy) [ size 11pt - already in the preamble]
 %%% START adjust spacing in ToC number %%% 
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@pnumwidth{2em} %more place for page number 
\makeatother %%% END adjust spacing in ToC number %%% 

\usepackage{setspace} % use for line spacing 
\onehalfspacing % line spacing = 1.5 
\usepackage{booktabs} % for rules within a table
\usepackage{parskip} 

\usepackage{ltablex} % for tables with long lines & long tables (over >1 page)
\usepackage{arabluatex} % for support of arabic fonts
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}[Script=Arabic, RawFeature={+anum}]
\usepackage{tikz} % for invalid images
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fvextra}

\usepackage{csquotes} % for quotes
\usepackage{eso-pic, transparent, pdfpages} % for the watermark
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{\AtPageCenter{\put(-40,-25){\rotatebox{55}{\makebox[0pt]{\transparent{0.5}\fontsize{3cm}{3cm}\bfseries\textcolor{red}{Draft}}}}}}
 %%% START fix for longtables incorrect page wrapping %%% 
\makeatletter
% copied from longtable.sty:
\def\LT@output{%
    \ifnum\outputpenalty <-\@Mi
    \ifnum\outputpenalty > -\LT@end@pen
    \LT@err{floats and marginpars not allowed in a longtable}\@ehc
    \else
    \setbox\z@\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv}%
    \ifdim \ht\LT@lastfoot>\ht\LT@foot
    \dimen@\pagegoal
    \advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@lastfoot
    \ifdim\dimen@<\ht\z@
    \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\z@\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
    \@makecol
    \@outputpage
    \setbox\z@\vbox{\box\LT@head}%
    \fi
    \fi
    \global\@colroom\@colht
    \global\vsize\@colht
    %       \vbox %<--- removing this box avoids the error
    {\unvbox\z@\box\ifvoid\LT@lastfoot\LT@foot\else\LT@lastfoot\fi}%
    \fi
    \else
    \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\copy\LT@foot\vss}%
    \@makecol
    \@outputpage
    \global\vsize\@colroom
    \copy\LT@head\nobreak
    \fi}
\makeatother %%% END fix for longtables incorrect page wrapping %%% 

% START: #xxx: Different colors
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\definecolor{coi_gray}{RGB}{136,155,169}
% Set formats for each heading level
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries\color{coi_gray}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalsize\bfseries\color{coi_gray}}
\usepackage[font=small, format=hang]{caption} % small font, an additional line as space after figure
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\bfseries\color{coi_gray}}
% END #xxx
\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={},
    pdftitle={Test, DRAFT},
    pdfsubject={DRAFT},
    urlcolor={blue},
    colorlinks={true},
    pdfcreator={my\hyp{}tex},
    pdfproducer={lualatex},
    linkcolor={black},
    pdfkeywords={afg},
}

\dump
```

and I generate the `fmt` file with `lualatex -ini  "&lualatex preamble.tex"`.

Any hints what's wrong with the definition? Is a matter of order? Package clash?

Comment: Well you have stuff in your preamble that you can't put in a format (like fonts).

Comment: you can not store any Lua state in a format file, so anything that loads OTF fonts or Lua back end files can not be loaded.

Comment: Beside `setmainfont{...` is there anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness:

I figured out that the following packages were not compatible

```
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{arabluatex} % for support of arabic fonts
\usepackage{tikz} % for invalid images
```

The mentioned fonts didn't cause any problems for compiliation. But might have an issue in a final version.

Additionally I want to note that the package `microtype` doesn't seem to work properly in a split. This is escpecially worth the note cuz this package requires as well some time for compilation. It took me a while a to recognize that I want compare apples with oranges.